# Asp.Net Web Config httpPlatform

Tags: asp.net

I am working on a Asp.net 5 project 
The Visual Studio is warning me that  is an invalid child for  tag in web.cong file in wwwroot folder of the project

While I'm running the project in gives an 500.19 - Internal Server Error.

So I guess there are Configuration issue. Can any one help me?

Comment: Paste the exact error message, not your own words. More info is always required.

Comment: That's ok, my Visual Studio also complains about "httpPlatform" tag. However my project works fine. Check that you have ASP.Net beta 8 web tools installed